# Why isn't the DAX Editor available in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, dax, visual-studio-extensions, ssas-tabular, daxstudio

1. Why isn't the DAX Editor available as an extension in Visual Studio 2017?
2. If it isn't available is there an alternative to it?
3. How do I get a list of defined measures in DAX studio similar to the "Model.dax" file generated in Visual Studio?

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue? Any feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't the DAX Editor available as an extension in Visual Studio
>   2017?

[DAX Editor extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DAXEditor.DAXEditor&ssr=false#qna) has not been updated to apply into VS2017 or later version so that you can use it in VS2015 or before. The team has not been updated this extension so far due to some resaons.

> If it isn't available is there an alternative to it?

ASAIK, there is a similar extension called [BISM Normalizer](http://bism-normalizer.com/)  and they are created by the same team but they may have a bit difference. As a suggestion, you can try my steps to modify `DaxEditor.vsix` installer.

**1)** download the installer from [this link](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DAXEditor.DAXEditor&ssr=false#qna)

**2)** use `open archive` from `7-zip` to open the installer `DaxEditor.vsix` and then open  `extension.vsixmanifest` file

[image]

**3)** modify like this:

change all the info `15.0` to `17.0`

[image]

**4)** Then save the option and then click the installer and l am sure that it can be installed into VS2017.

**Note**: Not sure this extension can work well in VS2017. It is not certain whether the core part is specific to a specific vs version. If the author is not asked to modify the core part, it may not be used, and there are compatibility problems.

**In addition**, if it still not work, please contact with [the author](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DAXEditor.DAXEditor&ssr=false#review-details) to apply into VS2017.

> How do I get a list of defined measures in DAX studio similar to the
>   "Model.dax" file generated in Visual Studio?

Sorry for that I am not similar with this and I think you can check [this document](https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/using-dax-editor/) for more detailed info.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thank you. I installed the Tabular Editor because I didn't want to run into any compatibility issues as you've mentioned in your note after (4).